# In what order SFMC execute SF API built in AMPscript functions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm having issues updating and retrieving SF objects data.
Is it possible that SFMC is executing `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` before `RetrieveSalesforceObjects` no matter the order in the script?

Here is the code.

```
var @EvaluationRow, @Evaluations, @EvaluationStatus
set @Evaluations = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Evaluation__c", "SDA_API_Log__c", "Id", "=", Evaluation_Id )
set @EvaluationRow = Row(@Evaluations, 1)
set @EvaluationStatus = Field(@EvaluationRow, "SDA_API_Log__c")

OutputLine(Concat(" EvaluationStatus is: ", @EvaluationStatus)) /*this always return Success*/

if @EvaluationStatus == 'Fail' then
   do something
   UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Evaluation__c',Evaluation_Id,'SDA_API_Log__c','Success')
endif
```

Even if the value of `SDA_API_Log__c` is `Fail` it will always output `Success`.

Comment: The code runs in the order it is written, so that is not your problem here. Where do you get the Evaluation_Id from? If this is all the code there is, it will not pass a real id in your query

Comment: `Evaluation_Id ` is coming from the send DE, this code is in an Email. Why wouldn't it pass the real Id?

Comment: Ah I overlooked that option, my apologies. In that case it might be as simple as just adding brackets because of special character. Like so: `[Evaluation_Id]`

As stated in "Attribute and Data Extension (Custom Object) Values" in these docs
 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm

Comment: Evaluation_Id works well. It's not the issue. I think there are some cashing issues MC do with lookups. It's a thing, and I think it's maybe the case here as well.

Comment: My hunch was that it might be passing a null value in the query and thus returning other records than you were expecting. Could you share a reference to the issue you are describing concerning caching?